# Javascript - Append a string to keys of an object including a dot character

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, object

I have the following `javacript object`:

```
Object {description: "This is a description."}
```

which I'm sending to the backend using the angular's `$http.get`, but I need to append a string to the key before sending it using a `.`

```
{bd.description: "This is a description."}
```

Is this possible?. So far I've been only able to create a `JSON` manually using the `.`
It'd like to avoid creating a template of a `JSON` and filling it later, as the number of properties of the `JSON` is variable.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** it's not a nested object.

Comment: of course it's possible, if you revise the question to creating an object key that has special characters.

Comment: Do you really want an object with a property with keyname `bd.description`, or is it supposed to be a property `bd` that is _another_ object that has a property of `description`?

Comment: @JamesThorpe I need to append that, it's not a nested object (I'm trying to match it to a  database query key, to make it generic).

Comment: you can't change an object key from x to x.x. you can however create a new object key/value pair with said key name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this if you would like:

```
var myObject = { description: "this is stuff" }
myObject['d.description'] = myObject.description
delete myObject.description
console.log(myObject) // { "d.description": "this is stuff" }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop on all object keys, then assign the values to a new object with modified keys like this

```
var source = { description: "..."}
// create empty object to hold new properties 
var destination = {}
for(var key in source) {
    if(source.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        // assign property to new object with modified key
        destination["bd." + key] = source[key];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new object like:

```
var bd = {
   description: yourobject.description
};
```

and return db;